# What file is this suppose to go in? Data path "" should have required property 'name'

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Working on upgrading this system I have from Angular 8 support to 11

And also trying to follow along a tutorial for Angular 11.

I have no idea what the output is trying to tell me.

What file to be populated with a 'path=value' & 'name=value'?

Where should this file be located?

```
$ ng new angular-hello-world
Run NG from node_modules of current project folder
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"version":"11.1.2"}
Errors:

  Data path "" should have required property 'name'.
```

Thoroughly confused here as I have been at this for 4 hours this morning and getting nowhere.

Comment: Still looking / Googling for the information on this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I found the cause of the issue. It was caused by the use of GitBash as my terminal in the Windows environment and a custom .bashrc file. Once I switched to the Windows terminal all issues went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that was creating the issue was something not properly configured within my .bashrc file.

I don't know what it was but once I put the default .bashrc back in play the command runs.

Leaving this post here just so anyone out there that runs into this may find this post.